# When pushing an integer onto the stack, how big is the holder for that int on the stack?

Tags: assembly, memory, stack, cpu-registers, stack-memory

So when you push a 32-bit register onto the stack, it will push a stack slide (I'm calling it a slide since I don't know the correct term) onto the stack that is 32-bit wide no matter what the register hold (1 or 2^32 unsigned).

My question is when we push an immediate like an integer or a hex value, how many bit is the slide? If I push 1, would the slide be 1 bit or 32 bits? The same with hex value?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: The register is a fixed size regardless of whether it holds the value of `1` or `2^31 - 1` as the 'integer' value (`dword`). `32-bits = 4-bytes`.

Comment: the size of bytes needed is always determined by the register's size, not by it's value. how shall `pop` otherwise know, how big the data `push`ed was ?

Comment: Yes, but what I'm asking is what happened if we push a integer without putting it in a register. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: and @Tommylee2k

Comment: You can push immediate *bytes*, *words* and *dwords* in x86 machine code - And the size this takes on the stack is exactly that size. It is up to your assembler and your input what operand size is taken.

Comment: @tofro on x86 you can't push *bytes*, only *words* and *dwords* (and *qwords* in 64b mode). @Jar you didn't specify CPU, some have only fixed size `push imm` instructions, some like x86 offer different `push` instructions, so you have to specify size in the source, depends on your Assembler what syntax it does use. Also there's NO difference between decimal, binary or hexadecimal immediate, that's just different way how to write the same value in your source. In machine code it will be the same numeric value encoded into some amount of bits (like 32). Ie. `push 0b1111 == push 0x0F == push 15`.

Comment: @Ped7g The *Intel 80186 programming manual* (80186 being the first x86 CPU to support PUSH for immediate values) says "*PUSH (push immediate) allows an immediate argument, data, to be pushed onto the stack. The value can be either a byte or a word. Byte values are sign extended to word size before being pushed*". There is also a separate opcode for "push byte immediate".

Comment: @tofro: `6A   PUSH imm8` ... hmm.. technically that *push* word value into stack, so it can't push byte anyway, but thanks, I was not aware of this shorter opcode.

Comment: @Ped7g Actually, there's quite a difference between `PUSH 080h` (byte)  and `PUSH 0080h` (word). The first one has a word of FF80h on the stack, the second 0080h

Comment: That's implied by the fact that it does a *sign* extension, rather than a zero extension. `PUSH 16h` would push `0016h` onto the stack.

Comment: Are you talking about x86 specifically in this question, or are you trying to ask about *all* possible architectures? On x86, the amount of space that is allocated on the stack (i.e., the amount by which the stack pointer is decremented) is determined by the size of the operand to the `PUSH` instruction. Immediate values are sign-extended. This is all covered by [the documentation](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html).

Comment: I would personally prefer to answer this question for stack-less platforms, I'm pretty sure there's no ambiguity whatsoever...